# Обособление оборота с "как" – выбор автора?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае наличие или отсутствие запятой перед "как" целиком зависит от воли автора?

> А может, мечта начинается
> С той песни, что пела мне мать?
> И жизнь пускай продолжается(,)
> Как сказка, что надо читать!

Если здесь чистое сравнение-уподобление, то запятая нужна. Если "как сказка" можно заменить на "по-сказочному" (и именно это хотел выразить автор), то запятая не нужна. Так? Или всё же вольности не приветствуются и регламентируются каким-то строгим правилом?

Comment: Да, вольность автора. "Она держится как хозяйка" (хозяйка входит в сказуемое или близко к нему. Запятую не ставим). Жизнь продолжается как сказка (аналогично). В то же время всегда можно сказать, что у нас просто сравнение и поставить запятую. Сравните ещё: "Год, как жизнь." "Небо как море". Жизнь (,) как сказка. А в таком оформлении уже строго по правилам: "Жизнь, словно сказка" и "Жизнь не как сказка". Хотя я не уверен, что перед "словно" прям уж обязательно ставить запятую...

Comment: @user190920  Спасибо! Перед *словно, будто, точно* и др. то же самое, что и с *как*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чаще всего автор проявляют свою "волю", пока составляет текст, а дальше при постановке знаков мы ориентируемся на структуру уже составленного предложения.

Текст песни «С чего начинается Родина»: *А может, она (Родина) начинается С той песни, что пела нам мать…*

*А может, мечта начинается*
*С той песни, что пела мне мать?*
*И жизнь пускай продолжается,*
***Как сказка, что надо читать**!*

**Пояснение**

Смысл здесь такой: *жизнь пусть продолжается **так, как читается сказка**.* Невозможно не обособить распространенный оборот, имеющий при себе **определительное придаточное**, и превратить его в обстоятельство «по-сказочному».

Невозможно, даже если это очень хочется сделать. Но в действительности заниматься "подстановками" – дело неблагодарное, потому что анализировать надо данное предложение, а не составленное по-другому.

**Примечание.** И  смысл «подстановки» совсем другой (это я для автора вопроса говорю, а не для автора комментария).  Подстановкой мы проверяем **не семантику, а позицию обстоятельства** – недавно это обсуждали.

(1) *Тропинка вьется **как змея*** (по-змеиному, это позиция обстоятельства образа действия).
(2) *Тропинка, **как змея**, вьется между холмов* (это уже попутное сравнение). Семантика не изменилась, а знаки  ставятся разные.

Comment: Спасибо! Автор текста попросил проверить, и я склонялся к тому, чтобы поставить запятую, но не смог убедить его в ее значении. Теперь есть авторитетный ответ!

Comment: @Sharon у меня только один вопрос. Нужна ли 2-ая запятая в предложении: "И жизнь пускай будет как сказка, что надо читать! " . Вас не смущает, что здесь "как сказка" входит в состав сказуемого ?

Comment: @user190920 Ну, со сказуемым, я думаю, вы сами разберетесь, но кое-что я вам всё-таки отвечу, хотя вы, признаться, меня разочаровали своими поступками. Когда жизнь как сказка – это здорово, я бы не отказалась. Ну, там ковры-самолеты, скатерти-самобранки и, конечно, принц на белом коне. А вот когда жизнь продолжается как сказка, вы, собственно, что имеете в виду? Если продолжается, значит,  продолжительность у них одинаковая? Да и сюжетная линия в сказках обычно несложная, композиционные приемы типовые..  Вот это мне уже не очень нравится.

Comment: А вообще  говоря, с такими вопросами вам бы к поэту обратиться. Это он определяет содержание и подбирает для этого нужную форму. Но если это сделать не совсем корректно, то не надо обижаться на читателей и говорить, что они его не так поняли. Вот вы пишете – «да, это вольность автора». Если так считать, то авторы или художники будут писать одно, а мы с вами читать или видеть другое. Я вам предлагаю красивую фразу: Жизнь продолжается, словно сказка читается. А вы что можете предложить,  логические схемы для корректного прочтения текста?

Comment: Дорогие участники, и автор этого незамысловатого текста выражает вам благодарность! Он принял решение изменить это предложение:  *И жизнь продолжается сказкой, Которую надо читать!* Так ведь правильно?

Comment: Я имею в виду полузнаменательную связку глагол "продолжать" (сохранение признака) в СИС. "Жизнь осталась сказкой". Здесь очевидное СИС. Жизнь продолжается как сказка = жизнь продолжила быть сказкой. Также СИС. Хотя не обязательно.

Comment: Не хватало еще подстраивать художественный текст под правила. Это правила должны подстраиваться под язык.

Comment: Лучше фонетику проверяйте и интонацию, а не о связках рассуждайте. Если не обособить оборот «продолжается, как сказка», то нельзя  поставить ударение на «продолжается», а сочетание «продолжается как сказка» нужно будет прочитать в одну фразу. Неудобно, некрасиво, ломается ритм стиха, зато очень логично по вашим схемам.

Answer (score 1):

```
И жизнь пускай продолжается (,) как сказка, что надо читать!
```

Возможно три варианта синтаксическо-семантической структуры предложения.

```
1. И жизнь как сказка, что надо читать, пускай продолжается.
```

Смысл такой: жизнь пускай будет как сказка и пускай она продолжается. "как сказка" входит в состав сказуемого и поэтому не обособляется.

```
2. И жизнь пускай продолжается сказкой, что надо читать!
```

Здесь сравнение при глаголе "продолжается как сказка" можно заменить творительным падежом существительного: "продолжается сказкой". В таких случаях запятая не ставится. Но у нас есть определительное придаточное при сказке. Меняет ли это дело? Не думаю, ведь распространяется существительное "сказкой", по стандартным процедурам.

```
3. И жизнь пускай продолжается, как сказка, что надо читать!
```

"Жизнь пускай продолжается, что похоже на то, как продолжается сказка!" . Попутное сравнение. "Как" можно заменить на "что похоже на то".

Какой же смысл имел в виду автор?

Если (2), то: Нужна ли 2-я запятая в предложении: "И жизнь пускай продолжается сказкой, что надо читать!". Очевидно, нет. Нужна ли запятая в исходном предложении, если оно эквивалентно (2) по смыслу? Воля автора, поскольку "Жизнь продолжается как сказка" можно переписать и как "Жизнь продолжается сказкой", и как "Жизнь продолжается так, как сказка".

Если (1), то опять-таки можно считать, что "как сказка" входит в состав сказуемого и предложение равносильно такому: "И жизнь пусть будет как сказка, что надо читать". А можно так не считать и ставить запятую, как в (3).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!